# Problem with custom class in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a little problem with the application I currenty work on. I create a simpliest project to illustrate my problem.

So, I create a "Navigate-Base Application". I add an other UITableViewController named TableViewController (the one which is created with the project is named RootViewController). I create an instance of TableViewController when I touch a line in the RootViewController.

I create a custom class named "MyCustomClass".

**MyCustomClass.h (full code) :**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyCustomClass : NSObject {
    NSString *name;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;

@end
```

**MyCustomClass.m (full code) :**

```
#import "MyCustomClass.h"

@implementation MyCustomClass

@dynamic name;

@end
```

I had a MyCustomClass attibute in TableViewController class.

**TableViewController.h (full code) :**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyCustomClass.h"

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController {
    MyCustomClass *aCustomObject;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MyCustomClass *aCustomObject;

@end
```

At the load of TableViewController, I try to display aCustomObject's content.

**TableViewController.m (top of the file and what I modify in the template's file) :**

```
#import "TableViewController.h"

@implementation TableViewController

@synthesize aCustomObject;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    NSLog(@"Name : %@",self.aCustomObject.name);
}
```

Before, I create and give a value to aCustomObject.name in RootViewController :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     TableViewController *detailViewController = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableViewController" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController.aCustomObject.name = @"The Name";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Console said :

> 2011-06-22 07:21:11.087
>   MyTestApp[12822:207] Name : (null)

I think it's a stupid thing but I don't find myself after hours of try.

Thanks a lot and excuse me for my english mistakes,

Answer (score 2):

You forget to initialize your custom object in the tableViewController's viewDidLoad Method.

Try this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
if(aCustomObject == nil){
   self.aCustomObject = [[[MyCustomClass alloc] init] autoRelease];
 }
self.aCustomObject.name = @"";
// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
 //this will show empty here.
NSLog(@"Name : %@",self.aCustomObject.name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. It crash with the message "[MyCustomClass setName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e12c40". And if I initialize my object in ViewDidLoad, I can't give a value when I create TableViewController in didSelectRowAtIndexPath's method of RootViewController.

Answer (score 2):

> You use the @dynamic keyword to tell
>   the compiler that you will fulfill the
>   API contract implied by a property
>   either by providing method
>   implementations directly or at runtime
>   using other mechanisms such as dynamic
>   loading of code or dynamic method
>   resolution. It suppresses the warnings
>   that the compiler would otherwise
>   generate if it can’t find suitable
>   implementations. You should use it
>   only if you know that the methods will
>   be available at runtime.

from [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW14)

You are claiming in the question that you included full source for `MyCustomClass.m`. Where did you implement the getter and setter for the property? If you want the compiler to generate the methods for you, you should use

```
@synthesize name;
```

Comment: Yes, you are perfectly right ! A f*#;+# copy/past from an class which inherits from NSManagedObject makes me become almost crazy. And after, I initialize aCustomObject and It works fine. Thank you very much both of you !